# Is it normal to have long files while working with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im learning flutter by making a website and I have noticed that some of the examples I have found online have just one or two really long .dart files. I am familiar with React and Im used to coding components in different files and then exporting them when needed, so I end up with several short files.

Is it okay to just have long files on flutter or do I have to follow the same React practices? If so, what is the best way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it depends on what you like and the complexity of your app. If you're making a huge app it would be better to separate files; if not, do as you feel it. But don't forget about coding best practices too.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the good practices it would be best for you and fellow teammates.

Some practices to reduce the code from the files are using View and Controller paradigm other is making separate widgets.

1. In the View-Controller, there you make a two files for a screen one is View which consists of the widgets function means it has the pure UI and Controller have all the business logic like your state management, your different computations and all.  View will be the mixin on state of the the controller like below and have the widget button and use it from the cntroller and pass the required fields.

   ```
   mixin HomScreenView on State<HomeScreenController> {
     Widget okButton(
        {required void Function()? onPressed, required String buttonText}) {
       return ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: Text(buttonText));
     }
   }
   ```

   where as controller state will extend the mixin like below:

   ```
   class _HomeScreenControllerState extends State<HomeScreenController>
       with HomeScreenView {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Center(
         child: okButton(onPressed: () {}, buttonText: 'Ok'),
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. And as the name says making separate widgets means making Stateful or mostly Stateless widgets.

   ```
   class OkButton extends StatelessWidget {


   const OkButton(
         {super.key, required this.buttonText, required this.onPressed});

     final String buttonText;
     final void Function()? onPressed;

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: Text(buttonText));
     }

   }
   ```

   Here you just make a separate widget and use it in your other files.